# Make watch not break down on error thrown by grunt-express-server

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I use Yeoman to do some angular development with grunt, livereload etc.

I've also set up a basic node.js/express app and I'm sharing some JS between the client (angular) and the server (node) using `grunt-contrib-copy` and `grunt-express-server` that fires on every file-save using watch. So far so good!

The problem is if I introduce a syntax error into the code that I want to share with node and hit save. The syntax error gets shown in the log and breaks/stops the watch. Then I have to go restart the watch in the console by doing `$ ctrl+c` and `$ grunt server`.

Is there a way to get `grunt-express-server` not to break/stop the watch that's going on if a syntax error is found in the js code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `grunt-express-server` and working the issue here:

> https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server/issues/27

I've been able to work around this problem by running `grunt-parallel` or `grunt-concurrent`, which prevents errors from preventing execution of watch.