# Stop Grunt Watch from breaking on code error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using the grunt-contrib-watch task.

I want to know if the is a way to stop the watcher breaking on code errors?

This is to speed up my work flow because it take 21 sec for restart the build and watch tasks.

Comment: Code errors in your gruntfile? Or are you using it to run other tasks? If so, what are those tasks?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. By code errors, you mean JS ?

Comment: It will depend of the plugin, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629946/make-watch-not-break-down-on-error-thrown-by-grunt-express-server?rq=1

Comment: No code error while I am developing, and yes I mean JS :)

Comment: What is your grunt version? Can you post your full grunt file?